# Phonegap Push Notification redirect to specific page in the application when clicking

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-build, forward

Using Phonegap Push Notifications Plugin to build a mobile application for IOS and Android, how proceed to let the notification received redirect or forward to a specific page in the application when the user clicked it? i.e. when receiving the notification, the user must open it to see it, we need to forward the application to a specific page, like notifications.html?id=USER_ID?

Is that any way to send the parameter USER_ID with the message pushed , The issue could be resolved in this case...

Thank you for your suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sent a push notification from your server includes an extra value name `id`.

When the notification is received then save the value of this "extra value" `id`  using `localStorage.setItem`.

then inside `onresume` event reads the value of this `id` using `localStorage.getItem`, and according the value open the respective page using `$.mobile.changePage( ...);`

for detail check this :

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/213